# add empty line before every line that contains certain characters

Tags: bash, regular-expression, string

I have a lot of markdown files that contains something like this:

```
* header A  
- item 1  
- item 2
** sub-header A1
** sub-header A2   
* header B  
- item 1  
- item 2  
** sub-header B1
** sub-header B2  
* header C  
- item 1  
- item 2 
** sub-header C1
** sub-header C2
```

and I want to alter them so the content becomes like this:

```
* header A  
- item 1  
- item 2
** sub-header A1
** sub-header A2   

* header B  
- item 1  
- item 2  
** sub-header B1
** sub-header B2  

* header C  
- item 1  
- item 2 
** sub-header C1
** sub-header C2
```

So basically the script should process a single file and add a new line before every line that contains only one asterisk, except the first line.

Also I would like a second script almost the same as the first one but which matches lines with any amount of asterisks in it, so if I have this:

```
* header A  
- item 1  
- item 2
** sub-header A1
** sub-header A2   
* header B  
- item 1  
- item 2  
** sub-header B1
** sub-header B2  
* header C  
- item 1  
- item 2 
** sub-header C1
** sub-header C2
```

I want to alter it to become:

```
* header A  
- item 1  
- item 2

** sub-header A1

** sub-header A2
   
* header B  
- item 1  
- item 2  

** sub-header B1

** sub-header B2  

* header C  
- item 1  
- item 2 

** sub-header C1

** sub-header C2
```

Comment: This is a questions and answers site, what is the question? What have you tried?

Comment: Your example contains no lines with multiple `*`'s so I don't know what such a line may look like. If there are multiple `*`'s, do they need to occur at the start together, as in `** something`, or should we also avoid `* * something` and `* something *`?

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
perl -i -ple 'print "" if $. > 1 && /^\s*\*(\*+|[^*]*)\s*/' your-file
```

Would print an empty line before any line (except the first) that start with any amount of whitespace then a `*` then either 1 or more additional `*` or no other `*` til the end allowing whitespace at the end. So either lines made of a sequence of more than one `*` or lines with one and only one `*` at the start (optionally preceded by whitespace, followed by anything).

With `-i`, the file is edited in-place.

If processing more than one file, you need a `close ARGV if eof` to make sure `$.` is reset to 1 after each file:

```
perl -i -ple '
  print "" if $. > 1 && /^\s*\*(\*+|[^*]*)\s*/;
  close ARGV if eof' ./*.md
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use `awk`. Something like can do the work:

```
 awk '/^*/ { if (FNR!=1) printf "\n"} {print $0}' <input file>
```

The idea is to search for record which start with `*` and check if this is not the first record. If both conditions are satisfied print empty line. Then print the input line.

The simplified version, offered in comment:

```
awk 'FNR > 1 && /^*/ {printf "\n"} 1'
```

P.S. This script have no problem with line with only `*` as far as it is on first position in the file.

Comment: Simplifying: `awk 'FNR > 1 && /^*/ {printf "\n"} 1'`

Comment: @glennjackman, you are right, will steal it for my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Another perl approach:

```
$ perl -ne 'print /^\*[^*]*$/ && $. > 1 ? "\n$_" : "$_"' file
* header A  
- item 1  
- item 2   

* header B  
- item 1  
- item 2  

* header C  
- item 1  
- item 2
```

This will print a newline before every line that starts with `*` and contains no other `*` anywhere except the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ed` with an editing script that inserts an empty line at each line that starts with the string `*` , from line 2 onwards:

```
2,$ g/^* / i \
\
.
```

The `g` command is applied to all lines from 2 to the last line (`$`), and it applies an `i` ("insert") command, which prepends an empty line to the lines matching the regular expression `^*` . Use `^*\**`  or `^*\{1,\}` to match a run of any non-zero number of `*`'s at the start of a line.

The `i` command looks a bit strange, but it's just

```
i

.
```

(i.e., insert an empty line), but we have to escape the newlines on all lines but the last since we execute it through a `g` command.

If instead of starting looking for lines that start with `*`  on the 2nd line, you want to start looking after the first line that start with `*` , then change the `2` in the command to something that steps you past the first `*` -line, for example `/^* /+1`.

Running this on the given data, with a couple of extra commands that print out the modified buffer and quit without saving:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' '2,$ g/^* / i\' '\' . ,p Q | ed -s file
* header A
- item 1
- item 2

* header B
- item 1
- item 2

* header C
- item 1
- item 2
```

Changing `,p` into `w` would write the modified buffer back into the original file.

---

A similar solution using `sed`:

```bash
sed -e 1b -e '/^* / i\

' file
```

... or, with GNU `sed`:

```bash
sed -e 1b -e '/^* / i \\' file
```

The `b` branches (jumps) to the given label, or to the end of the script if there is no label.  We use it here to explicitly do nothing to the first line.  We then apply an insertion command that prepends an empty line to all lines that start with `*` .

Comment: thank you for the explanation, that pattern matches lines that starts with `*` effectively matching headers of all levels (which answers my side question), but what if I want to match lines that contain one and only one `*`?

Comment: @GhostOrder Your example contains no lines with multiple `*`'s so I don't know what such a line may look like. If there are multiple `*`'s, do they need to occur at the start together, as in `** something`, or should we also avoid `* * something` and `* something *`?

Comment: @GhostOrder I have modified the answer to look for lines that contain a `*` followed by a space at the start of a line.

Comment: I've just edited the question adding the other example

Comment: @GhostOrder Thanks. My code should handle that already.

Comment: your code handles the first case: matching lines that contains only one `*`, but it doesn't handle the second case: matching lines that contains any amount of `*`

Comment: @GhostOrder I made an addition that mentions how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'S:g/ (^^ \*   <-[*]>* ) $$ /\n$0/.trim-leading.put  given slurp;'     file

#OR

~$ raku -e 'S:g/ (^^ \*\* <-[*]>* )+  /{$0.join}\n/.trim-trailing.put given slurp;'   file
```

These two answers give the OP's desired first transformation, and Raku is a good choice (in general) if you need to handle Unicode text.

- In the first code example, the file is `slurp`ed in and individual `^^` lines starting with a single `\*` asterisk, followed by `<-[*]>*` zero-or-more non-asterisks, followed by `$$` end-of-line, are `(…)` captured into `$0`. Then `\n$0` is placed  the replacement, with the caveat that something like `.trim-leading` must be used to remove whitespace inserted at the *top* of the OP's example file.
- In the second code example, the file is `slurp`ed in and `(…)+` one-or-more `^^` lines starting with a double `\*\*` asterisk, followed by `<-[*]>*` zero-or-more non-asterisks, followed by `$$` end-of-line, are captured into `$0`. Then `{$0.join}\n` is placed  the replacement, with the caveat that something like `.trim-trailing` must be used to remove whitespace inserted at the *bottom* of the OP's example file.

Sample Input:

```
* header A  
- item 1  
- item 2
** sub-header A1
** sub-header A2   
* header B  
- item 1  
- item 2  
** sub-header B1
** sub-header B2  
* header C  
- item 1  
- item 2 
** sub-header C1
** sub-header C2
```

Sample Output:

```
* header A  
- item 1  
- item 2
** sub-header A1
** sub-header A2   

* header B  
- item 1  
- item 2  
** sub-header B1
** sub-header B2  

* header C  
- item 1  
- item 2 
** sub-header C1
** sub-header C2
```

---

The OP's request for a *second* script that visually offsets lines with `\*+` one-or-more asterisks is actually easier. It's based on the first example above, and here's that solution (note `.trim` at the end):

```
~$ raku -e 'S:g/ (^^ \*+ <-[*]>* $$) /\n$0/.trim.put given slurp;'  file
* header A  
- item 1  
- item 2

** sub-header A1

** sub-header A2   

* header B  
- item 1  
- item 2  

** sub-header B1

** sub-header B2  

* header C  
- item 1  
- item 2 

** sub-header C1

** sub-header C2
```

https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org